# Unable to understand why typed.js won't work

Tags: jquery, animation

I can't understand why this isn't working. Using Typed.js, it should animate text (like typing). Example: I found... hope/family.

Key head elements:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typed.js"></script>
<script> var typed = new Typed('#typing', {strings: ["hope", "family"], typeSpeed: 30 });
</script>
```

I have additionally tried...

```
<script>$(function(){$("#typing").typed({strings: ["hope", "family"], typeSpeed: 0});});</script>
```

Key body elements:

```
<h2 class="heading-black-36-1">I found <span id="typing"></span></h2>
```

See: https://www.citychurchchristchurch.co.nz/index

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you actually initializing Typed? Something like: `var typed = new Typed(".element", options);`

Comment: @jonmrich I've now updated the op to **<script>
  var typed = new Typed('.typing', {
  strings: ["hope", "family"],
  typeSpeed: 30
  });</script>** Still doesn't work.

Comment: That was just an example...do you actually have a class named `element`?

Comment: @jonmrich My mistake. Correction made. #typing. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
strings: ["hope", "family"],
typeSpeed: 40
}
var typed = new Typed("#typing", options);
});
```

You can either put this in `<script>` tags or in a js file in your footer. But this needs to come AFTER (later in page) than this line:

```
<h2 class="heading-black-36-1">I found <span id="typing"></span></h2>
```

Comment: I tried this (refer op link). Still doesn't work. Your answer seems right to me so I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Try putting that script in my answer BELOW where you load jquery (around link 440 on your site)

Comment: Thank you @jonmrich for all your efforts. Done. Still no result.

Comment: The warning in the console means that it's not finding the Typed library. You load it in your head with `<script src="typed.js"></script>`, but looking at the sources of your page, I don't actually see a `typed.js` file. Are you sure that's the correct path to the file?

Comment: That's interesting. I can see the file sitting in the root folder.

Comment: Click on the link in the source and it's right there

Comment: Also you put the script in my answer ABOVE jquery...it needs to be below.

Comment: Instead of `<script src="typed.js"></script>`...try...`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>`

Comment: And you're loading jquery twice.

Comment: Working through now. Thank you.

Comment: Great news. The code could use just a little cleanup here and there. I think you have a few duplicate things, but the site looks good and seems to function well and there are no meaningful errors in the console, so I wouldn't worry a ton about all that.

Comment: It's great feedback. Already I'm working my way through to correct some things. Leaning all the time, though really a front-end developer/designer. I really appreciate all your efforts. Thanks again.